# C program to convert binary fraction to decimal

Tags: c, binary, fractions

I have 64 bits that are all supposed to be behind the decimal (0.000.....0), how can I convert this binary fraction to a decimal in C preferably without a lot of iterations or loops.

For example:

> I have int x = 2218 which is 100010101010 thats supposed to represent 0.100010101010 converted into a decimal  (in this case it would be 0.54150390625)

Comment: I'm assuming msb = 0.5 and lsb = 2^-64?

Comment: @ImportAccelerate yes

Comment: If you look at https://www.exploringbinary.com/a-table-of-negative-powers-of-two/ you can see that each decrement in the exponent = increase in digits. Thus, you can have a table of all the fractional part of the numbers 2^-1 to 2^-64 and then you can generate the result with a single loop that adds the corresponding number to the accumulator and multiplied the accumulator by 10.

Comment: Thus, with 3 bits 101 -> `(((0 + t[0]) * 10 + 0) * 10) + t[2]` = `(((5 * 10) + 0) * 10) + 125` == 625, which you can prepend with a `"0."` for `0.625`.

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: @ImportAccelerate Thank you!

Comment: The reason I didn't give an answer is so you could figure out all the heavy lifting by yourself. But if you have any more questions, feel free to let me know.